# How to change property of features in a FeatureCollection where there is overlapping?

Tags: google-earth-engine, overlapping-features, feature-collection

I have two feature collections and I want to change the features' property in one collection based on the other one where there is overlapping, but it seems that I just merge and keep both features where they overlap.

```
Map.addLayer(Grid,{color:'red'},'Grid')
var Fcorrectioend=function(feature){
                    var day=ee.Number.parse((ee.String(feature.get('event_date'))).slice(8))
                    var Month=ee.Number.parse((ee.String(feature.get('event_date'))).slice(5,7))
                    var Year=ee.Number.parse((ee.String(feature.get('event_date'))).slice(0,4))
                    var date=ee.Date.fromYMD(Year,Month,day)
                            return feature.set('system:time_start',date)
                              };
var test=table.map(Fcorrectioend) 

var day1=test.filterDate('2020-01-01','2020-01-02')
Map.addLayer(day1,{},'day1')
print(day1)

var test=(day1.merge(Grid)).select('event_count')
Map.addLayer(test,{color:'green'},'testMerge')
```

Here is the link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/7378c612af5339f972f6fc0b0e9ad85c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple ways to do it; I'm not sure which one would be best for large collections. Probably the second one, but I haven't tested their performance.

We can, for each feature, look for an intersecting feature:

```js
var all = collection1.map(function (feature) {
  return feature.set('intersects', 
    collection2
      // Match features in collection2 that intersect this feature of collection1
      .filter(ee.Filter.intersects('.geo', feature.geometry()))
      // And test if there's at least one.
      .limit(1).size());
});
```

Or we could use joins to find both matches and non-matches, then combine them:

```js
var intersectsFilter = ee.Filter.intersects({leftField: '.geo', rightField: '.geo'});

var matches = ee.Join.simple().apply(collection1, collection2, intersectsFilter)
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('intersects', true);
  });
var nonMatches = ee.Join.inverted().apply(collection1, collection2, intersectsFilter)
  .map(function (feature) {
    return feature.set('intersects', false);
  });

var all = matches.merge(nonMatches);
```

Demo: https://code.earthengine.google.com/057d12519093db2fa61503570fe912d9

Comment: Thank you, Kevin! Both did a beautiful job, though I used the second one as the main function.